# Is there an FTP server for testing error conditions?

Tags: testing, ftp, integration-testing

One of the products I am maintaining has FTP uploads as part of its core functionality. We are encountering problems in production where the FTP server times out and the system doesn't react too well to that.

Is there an FTP server that I can use for testing scenarios like that? I want to be able to deliberately fail in different ways such as:

- refuse connection (that one's easy)
- stall until sockets time out
- close connections in the middle of transmissions

Ideally it would let us configure behavior such as "drop the connection on every third upload, 300 bytes in".

I can see how to write this based e.g. on the Apache FTP server code, but I wonder if I am re-inventing a wheel. Is there an FTP server already that I can make fail in a controlled fashion?

Comment: It'd probably be pretty straightforward to hack this together in python. Personally, I think I'd do that before hacking up some real FTP server code.